# Does git cherry-pick -n and git commit equal to git add and git commit

Tags: git

For example, currently in branch `master` and status is clean:

A:

```
echo "test" >> README.md
git add README.md && git commit -m "asdf" ## commit id: AAAA
```

Then `CommitDate` and `AuthorDate` is same

B:

```
git checkout -b asdf
echo "test" >> README.md
git add README.md && git commit -m "asdf" ## commit id: BBBB
git checkout master
sleep 100 && git cherry-pick BBBB
```

Then `CommitDate` and `AuthorDate` is different

Instead of B, if I do C:

C:

```
git checkout -b asdf
echo "test" >> README.md
git add README.md && git commit -m "asdf" ## commit id: CCCC
git checkout master
sleep 100 && git cherry-pick -n CCCC && git commit -m "asdf"
```

Then `CommitDate` and `AuthorDate` is same

Except the hash id, are `A` and `C` same essentially? Is there anyway to figure out a commit is done by `A` or `C`??

Comment: It's not clear what you are really asking about here: is it strictly about the difference between author and committer records in each commit, and how cherry-pick affects them?

Answer (score 0):

In C you are doing `git cherry-pick -n CCCC` and then `git commit -m "asdf"` the -n flag for cherry-pick denotes a `no-commit` which means that the cherry picked commit from the other branch are not committed but the necessary changes of the commit are made in the current working branch. So a new commit is made when `git commit -m "asdf"` is done.

> **-n** or
>   **--no-commit** : Usually the command automatically creates a commit. This flag applies the change necessary to cherry-pick the named commit to
>   your working tree and the index, but does not make the commit. In
>   addition, when this option is used, your index does not have to match
>   the HEAD commit. The cherry-pick is done against the beginning state
>   of your index.
>
> This is useful when cherry-picking more than one commits' effect to
>   your index in a row.

In B you are doing `git cherry-pick BBBB` without the -n flag and so the commit is automatically made with the commit from A.

So in C, the commit id refers to the commit made by C.
In B, the commit id refers to the commit made by A.